# How can i import a scss file into another scss file using the scssphp compiler?

Tags: php, sass, compass-sass

I'm using the scssphp compiler so that my scss files get compiled server side using the PHP framework and not the default Ruby SASS watch. Somehow the functionality to include scss files inside the current scss file doesn't work.

The code I have:

```
@import 'grid';
```

_grid.scss is in the same directory as the current scss file. What am I doing wrong or could it be that the scssphp compiler doesn't have this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you may need to configure the `@import` path. From the docs:

> When you import a file using the @import directive, the current path
>   of your PHP script is used as the search path by default. This is
>   often not what you want, so there are two methods for manipulating the
>   import path: `addImportPath`, and `setImportPaths`.
>
> - addImportPath($path) will append $path to the list of the import paths
>     that are searched.
> - setImportPaths($pathArray) will replace the entire import path with
>     $pathArray. The value of $pathArray will be converted to an array if
>     it isn’t one already.
>
> If the import path is set to array() then importing is effectively
>   disabled. The default import path is array(""), which means the
>   current directory.

You can read more about this [here](http://leafo.net/scssphp/docs/#import_paths)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't fully understand what the functionality of addImportPath and setImportPaths was but apparently it was what I was searching after all.